# Alguien podria explicarme como funciona la explicacion de los metodos de VSCODE

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vscode, sintaxis

Estoy aprendiendo soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y estoy aprendiendo js - node js y siempre me he preguntado cuando veo los métodos me aparecen como en la foto los signos de `?` y `:` y también en el caso del listener `() =>`.

Creo entender que el signo de  de interrogación (`?`) significa opcional y los  dos puntos (:) es el tipo de dato.

Y en el caso del listener es una función (¿este listener también se puede llamar *callback*?) que retorna void y todo este método retorna un objeto de tipo server?

¿Cómo se llama ese tipo de sintaxis si lo podría llamar así para poder investigar un poco?

¿Alguien me podría aclarar si estoy en lo correcto ?

Otra pregunta ¿Por qué al lado de server dice *+8 overloads*?

[image: VS studio code]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y estas en lo corrrecto en todo.. y el +8 overloads quiere decir que hay 8 definiciones mas de ese metodo, con otros parametros

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por la ayuda !